# Making Android library for common utils

Tags: java, android, deployment, guava

I am making Android library for used by my project that needs some common utilities.

And,

1. In my project (using Android Studio), I set up the Lint checking, `@NotNull/@Nullable problems` as error severity.
2. In my common utilities library, there is a class, DebugPreconditions, that involves a lot of condition checking. As,

   ```
   DebugPreconditions.checkNotNull(fragment);
   Bundle bundle = fragment.getArguments();
   bundle.putString(MainActivity.ARGS_SHOP_ID, shopId);
   activity.replaceFragment(fragment, R.id.fragment_container, true);
   ```

DebugPreconditions.checkNotNull,

```
/**
 * Ensures that an object reference passed as a parameter to the calling method is not null.
 * @param <T>       the type parameter
 * @param reference an object reference
 * @return the non-null reference that was validated
 * @throws NullPointerException if {@code reference} is null
*/
public static <T> T checkNotNull(@Nullable T reference) {
    if (reference == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return reference;
}
```

The issue I met is, 
Android Inspection still found there is problem could cause 'NullPointerException' on `fragment.getArguments()

[image]

But if I use Google Guava's [Preconditions.checkNotNull](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull(T)) the error notification will be gone.

Anyone can help me??

Comment: I think my code is almost the same to [Guava Preconditions.checkNotNull](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/android/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java#L780)

Comment: Unless Java compiler does behind, it might what I am wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Ensures that an object reference passed as a parameter to the calling method is not null.
 * @param <T>       the type parameter
 * @param reference an object reference
 * @return the non-null reference that was validated
 * @throws NullPointerException if {@code reference} is null
*/
@NotNull // <-- This is important.
public static <T> T checkNotNull(@Nullable T reference) {
    if (reference == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return reference;
}
```

And when you call `DebugPreconditions.checkNotNull`, assign the return value back to the reference variable. Like this:

```
fragment = DebugPreconditions.checkNotNull(fragment);
```

Comment: If `fragment` is declared `final` it doesn't work. And how to achieve like  Google Guava's Preconditions.checkNotNull? I don't understand what's difference with it, mine and it are the same...

Comment: @lekaha try removing the `@Nullable` annotation from the argument `T reference`

Comment: So now the error moved on the line of the checking, `DebugPreconditions.checkNotNull(fragment);`